# Timer in matlab to repeat segments of code every few minutes

Tags: matlab, loops, timer, while-loop

I have the following code which downloads a CSV file from a link and then saves it as a formatted file:

```
urlwrite('http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/JCMB_2013_Sep.csv','Weather Data.csv');
data= readtext('Weather Data.csv');
```

I want to download download this file every 5 minutes. The updated data from the file is used in other parts of my script so I also want those calculations and other parts of my program to be automated every 5 minutes with the change in new file information.

The timer feature in matlab calls a function and i'd rather do it as a loop format because my calculations aren't already saved as specific functions.

How can I achieve this as some sort of loop or timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way might be to put in a pause command, `pause(t)` pauses the script for `t` seconds, so you could have

```
while(1)
    tic
    urlwrite('http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/JCMB_2013_Sep.csv','Weather Data.csv');
    data= readtext('Weather Data.csv');
    % run the rest of the code that you need to run on the data you have downloaded
    T=toc;
    pause(300-T)
end
```

You can terminate the loop by pressing ctrl+c, which will stop the code.

Hope that helps

Comment: Dear David, for the above code example what would the for statement be since I am not referencing any integer value in the loop? Thanks for your help. I will read up more on pause(t).

Comment: @loco Well it depends what you want your code to do really, I just used `for` as a generic loop. If you want to run it indefinitely, then you can replace `for ...` with `while(1)`, and include some termination condition. If your code takes some time to run, then this may cause problems as it will run the code then wait 5 minutes, rather than running the code then waiting until 5 minutes is up. I will edit my answer to account for that.

Comment: Oh ok. I want the code to repeat every 5 minutes permanently. I.e the script/program is running the whole time and continually updating with new information and performing calculations with the newly extracted info. Currently it takes the script around 17 seconds to download and store the data. Thanks.

Comment: In that case a `while` loop is your best bet. Just use `while(1)`, but still include some termination condition (use `break` to exit out of the while loop).

Comment: Sorry but can you explain why to use while(1) as opposed to while %any other condition?

Thanks for the help. I'm new to MATLAB/programming so apologies if I seem a little 'slow'.

Comment: I'll put it in my answer. A while loop works by testing a condition, and running the loop if the condition is true, then testing it again, running if it's true, etc. etc. If the condition is false, it will leave the loop. To make the loop repeat indefinitely, ensure the condition is always true, so you can use `while(true)`, or equivalently `while(1)`.

Comment: i've edited the answer to show my code, with a %break statement which i've tested with and without (MATLAB just holds busy). Should I only include the break statement if I only want the program to stop running or is it still required in order to execute the later segments of code since it uses an interpreter for compiling. I can continue in MATLAB chat if that is easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40346/discussion-between-david-and-loco)