# How can I run Matlab .m file repetitive in background?

Tags: matlab

I have project that was wrote in MATLAB. It has Main file like `Main.m`, I want to run `Main.m` repetitive every **1 Second** in background.
I don't want to see any display and opening windows from MATLAB.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps to achieve this. First write some m script which calls your Main function every 1s. You can [use a loop like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19717845/2732801) Getting the time via toc is important in case your main function takes some time to compute. An alternative are [timers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21014647/2732801), which avoid any time drift (The loop is typically slightly above 1s, the timer will be 1s on average).

Once your MATLAB knows what to do, the question is who to start it. There is the `-batch` option:

> Execute MATLAB script, statement, or function non-interactively.
>   MATLAB:
>
> - Starts without the desktop
> - Does not display the splash screen
> - Executes statement
> - Disables changes to preferences
> - Disables toolbox caching
> - Logs text to stdout and stderr
> - Does not display dialog boxes
>
> Exits automatically with exit code 0 if script executes successfully.
>   Otherwise, MATLAB terminates with a non-zero exit code.
>
> statement is MATLAB code enclosed in double quotation marks. If
>   statement is the name of a MATLAB function or script, do not specify
>   the file extension. Any required file must be on the MATLAB search
>   path or in the startup folder.
>
> Use the -batch option in non-interactive scripting or command line
>   work flows. Do not use this option with the -r option.
>
> To test if a session of MATLAB is running in batch mode, call the
>   batchStartupOptionUsed function.
>
> Example: -batch "myscript"

This means MATLAB will not open any window, instead you see any output in the calling command line. How it looks on LINUX:

```
x@y ~ $ matlab -batch "1+1"

ans =

     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a top-level function in `Main.m` that you would like to execute once every 1 second, one possibility is to start an instance of Matlab and create another script that calls your function in a forever loop with a 1 second pause (making sure that this other script has Main.m file in the `PATH` so it can see it)

function run_main_forever()
    while true
        my_function()
        pause(1)
    end
end

You can have a .bat file start matlab in the background and run the script like this:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "cd('C:\Path\To\'); run_main_forever();"
```

See this link for further details on launching MATLAB without the desktop: https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/

Comment: This solution is not suitable for my purpose, Because I didn't want to open Matlab, I want to run Matlab in background (for example with double click of `.bat` file that included command lines)

Comment: I updated my answer to include starting the script from a `.bat` file

Comment: You might have better timing regularity using a Matlab Timer instead of a pause/for loop. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html `pause` is not guaranteed to be accurate in terms of timing. I think your approach of using a helper script is the right way, though. Matlab startup is too slow to get close to being able to launch once a second.